A change in the unit vector over a finite time interval
how we can write the change in unit vectors over a finite time interval, the change in unit vectors in an infinitesimally small-time interval 'dt' is given by the magnitude of the really small angle that the unit vector has turned about, but what about a change in the unit vector over a finite time interval how can we write that.

The way one can write changes depends on what the change is, of course.  However, in general, changes in unit vectors are expressed in one of several forms.  The most common are:

A rotation matrix (which is a bit over-constrained, as it transforms all unit vectors, not just one)
Changes in spherical position (azimuth and elevation)

The rate of change of a unit vector over an infinitesimally small rotation is a special case of the rotation matrix.  In this infinitely small case, it works out that the change in a rotation matrix $R$ can be expressed as $\frac d{dt}R=[\omega]_\times\cdot R$, where $[\omega]_\times$ is a Skew Symmetric Matrix representation for a cross product with a vector $\omega$.  This $\omega$ is the vector you referenced when talking about the infinitesimal rate of change.
As we often find, the infinitesimal calculus version of these transformations is far simpler to write down than the finite version.  We find this happens quite often as a consequence of derivatives naturally moving the thinking into a linear space, which is often much simpler than the original space one operated on.
